# JSON parse with PHP get information

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I'm trying to parse a few pieces of information from a JSON data structure with PHP. My foreach is working really odd:

```
[query] => Array (
 [count] => 2
 [created] => 2014-05-12
 [lang] => de-DE
 [results] => Array (
     [rate] => Array (
         [0] => Array (
             [id] => 1
             [Name] => User1
             [Rate] => 64.5245
             [Date] => 8/13/2013
             )
         [1] => Array (
             [id] => 2
             [Name] => User2
             [Rate] => 71.9697
             [Date] => 8/3/2014
             )
         )
     )
 )
```

I need to parse **Name**, **Rate** and **created** (date from the beginning of the array).

My code is:

```
foreach ($json_var['query']['results']['rate'][0] as $key=>$value) {
    echo $value['Name'];
}
```

But I'm getting to many errors. If I try without [0] I get the name of both users.

Can you guys please help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you want to get only the name and rate on the first index?

Comment: Of the first and of the second index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: Hope this helps you

```
$newArray = [];
   foreach ($json_var['query']['results']['rate'] as $key=>$value) {
     $newArray['NameAndRate'][] = ['Name' =>$value['Name'], 'Rate' =>$value['Rate']];
     $newArray['create'] = $jsonVar['query']['create'];
    }
print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: No problem sir @DraugDev. Glad to help.